# Angular 2 - template parse error for an input parameter in the component

Tags: angular

I am paginating posts in my component and I am sending the number of posts from the post component to pagination component to like this:

```html
<pagination [items]="posts.length" (page-changed)="onPageChanged($event)"></pagination>
```

I have set up the pagination component and the parameter items like so:

```typescript
export class PaginationComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() items: number;
```

But, I get an error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known native property ("
        </select>
        <spinner [visible]="postsLoading"></spinner>
        <pagination [ERROR ->][items]="posts.length" (page-changed)="onPageChanged($event)"></pagination>
        <ul class="list-g"): PostsComponent@10:20
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the complete pagination component:

```typescript
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {OnChanges} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
      selector: 'pagination',
    template: `
    <nav *ngIf="items > pageSize">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li [class.disabled]="currentPage == 1">
                <a (click)="previous()" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [class.active]="currentPage == page" *ngFor="#page of pages" (click)="changePage(page)">
                <a>{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
            <li [class.disabled]="currentPage == pages.length">
                <a (click)="next()" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
`
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() items: number;
    @Input('page-size') pageSize = 10;
    @Output('page-changed') pageChanged = new EventEmitter();
    pages: any[];
    currentPage;

    ngOnChanges(){
    this.currentPage = 1;

        var pagesCount = Math.ceil(this.items / this.pageSize);
        this.pages = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++)
            this.pages.push(i);
    }

    changePage(page){
        this.currentPage = page;
        this.pageChanged.emit(page);
    }

    previous(){
        if (this.currentPage == 1)
            return;

        this.currentPage--;
        this.pageChanged.emit(this.currentPage);
    }

    next(){
        if (this.currentPage == this.pages.length)
            return;

        this.currentPage++;
        this.pageChanged.emit(this.currentPage);
    }
}
```

And this is the posts component:

```typescript
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {PostService} from '../services/post.service';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';
import {SpinnerComponent} from './spinner.component';
import {PaginationComponent} from './pagination.component';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/posts.template.html',
    styles: [`
        .posts li { cursor: default; }
        .posts li:hover { background: #ecf0f1; }
        .list-group-item.active,
        .list-group-item.active:hover,
        .list-group-item.active:focus {
            background-color: #ecf0f1;
            border-color: #ecf0f1;
            color: #2c3e50;
        }
        .clickable {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .thumbnail {
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
    `],
    providers: [PostService, UserService],
    directives: [SpinnerComponent]
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
      posts = [];
    users = [];
    pagedPosts = [];
    postsLoading;
    commentsLoading;
    currentPost;
    pageSize = 10;

    constructor(
        private _postService: PostService,
        private _userService: UserService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadUsers();
        this.loadPosts();
    }

    private loadUsers(){
        this._userService.getUsers()
          .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
    }

    private loadPosts(filter?){
        this.postsLoading = true;
            this._postService.getPosts(filter)
                .subscribe(
              posts => {
                  this.posts = posts;
                  this.pagedPosts = this.getPostsInPage(1);
              },
              null,
              () => { this.postsLoading = false; });
    }

    reloadPosts(filter){
        this.currentPost = null;

        this.loadPosts(filter);
    }

    select(post){
            this.currentPost = post;

        this.commentsLoading = true;
        this._postService.getComments(post.id)
            .subscribe(
                comments => this.currentPost.comments = comments,
                null,
                () => this.commentsLoading = false);
    }

    onPageChanged(page) {
          this.pagedPosts = this.getPostsInPage(page);
    }

    private getPostsInPage(page){
        var result = [];
            var startingIndex = (page - 1) * this.pageSize;
        var endIndex = Math.min(startingIndex + this.pageSize, this.posts.length);

        for (var i = startingIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
            result.push(this.posts[i]);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is the template:

```html
<h1>Posts</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <select class="form-control" (change)="reloadPosts({ userId: u.value })" #u>
            <option value="">Select a user...</option>
            <option *ngFor="#user of users" value="{{ user.id }}">
                {{ user.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
        <spinner [visible]="postsLoading"></spinner>
        <pagination [items]="posts.length" (page-changed)="onPageChanged($event)"></pagination>
        <ul class="list-group posts">
            <li *ngFor="#post of pagedPosts" class="list-group-item" [class.active]="currentPost == post" (click)="select(post)">
                {{ post.title }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div *ngIf="currentPost" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">{{ currentPost.title }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{ currentPost.body }}</p>
                <hr/>
                <spinner [visible]="commentsLoading"></spinner>
                <div class="media" *ngFor="#comment of currentPost.comments">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object thumbnail" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/people?random={{ comment.id }}" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">
                            {{ comment.name }}
                        </h4>
                        {{ comment.body }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you code looks fine ,just check if you saved your files or restart your project.

Comment: I did, but I still get the same error

Comment: Can you post some more code? I tried it out, and it works in my case... Maybe just remove the built code and re-run the build-process? This often helps...

Comment: Ah, have you set the "selector" to `pagination` in the `PaginationComponent`?

Comment: I have updated question with more code. I am using the selector 'pagination'.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add a `pagination` component to the `directives` array in the `posts` component.